# how to reach a certain number by adding the elements of an list

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am trying to write a program to spend all the money that I have in this case 32.
the item at larger index has more personal value hence the goal is to spend on higher index but also to spend all the money

```
l = [7,8,9,8,7,9,8,8,10]
l[8]+l[7]+l[4]+l[4]=32
```

Comment: If you have tried to write code for your problem ,please post that code.

Comment: No, this came as an intermediate case in a problem and i got stuck in how to create the logic for this